# What are the most general boundary conditions for which the wave/Klein–Gordon equation is known to be well posed?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation, klein-gordon-equation

I'm working on problems related to the inhomogeneous [Klein–Gordon equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation) ($[\partial_t^2 - \nabla^2 + m^2]\phi(t,\mathbf{x}) = F(t,\mathbf{x})$), and I started to consider how general I could make the boundary conditions. For elliptic differential equations I know that you can have [Dirichlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_boundary_condition) ($\phi$ fixed on boundary), [Neumann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_boundary_condition) ($\partial_{\hat{n}}\phi \equiv \hat{n}\cdot\nabla\phi$ fixed on boundary), and [Robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_boundary_condition) (linear combination of Dirichlet & Neumann) boundary conditions. The Robin boundary conditions can be generalized in a fairly straightforward way by considering a local function of $\phi$ and $\partial_{\hat{n}}\phi$.

In detail, if we assume that
\begin{align}
  f(\phi, \partial_{\hat{n}}\phi,\mathbf{x}) &= \alpha(\mathbf{x})
\end{align}
is the boundary condition then, as long as $f$ satisfies
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \phi^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial (\partial_{\hat{n}}\phi)^2} &= 0 \\
  \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial (\partial_{\hat{n}}\phi)}\right)^2 & > 0
\end{align}
for all $\mathbf{x}$, then we can construct a [harmonic conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_conjugate) to $f$ called $g$. Because the relationship between $(\phi,\partial_{\hat{n}}\phi)$ and $(f,g)$ is everywhere invertible, we can then use $g$ in the process of working out what boundary conditions the Green's function has to satisfy to construct a solution for $\phi$ that satisfies the static Klein–Gordon equation (generalization of Poisson's equation) and boundary conditions.

With the full Klein–Gordon equation we have the addition of [Cauchy boundary conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_boundary_condition) (initial/final value problems). Is there a similarly general way to construct the boundary conditions in this problem? I mean, we could consider the generalization of Robin-like boundary conditions for the initial and final space-like time slices in the exact same way, but I'm having trouble thinking of a similarly general mixing in of Cauchy type boundary conditions. The sticking point is that the Robin-type mixing of Dirichlet and Neumann is purely local. With Cauchy boundary conditions you over-specify data on one boundary and leave the data on the other boundary completely unspecified. This is a non-local interchange, and because of this I cannot think of how to interpolate among initial, final, and Robin boundary conditions in a way that is assured to keep the problem well-posed.

Comment: If $F(x,t)=h(\phi(x,t))$ then I think it is possible to express the KG operator as the second derivative in the complex spacetime. This in turn can be formulated as an integral over the complex plane boundary, i.e. initial, boundary and final conditions in the real. Thus $\phi(x,t)=h^{-1}(\oint \ldots)$.

Comment: @Cretin2 Nice idea, but $d=2$ is a rather special case and I'm more interested in the general case.

Comment: Ok. For this idea maybe a quaternionic integral theorem similar to Cauchy would be needed, but I'm not used to those constructions.